# Portable IRC client for Windows with rudimental scripting and log support

Tags: windows-xp, irc

I'm looking for a ***portable (does not need installation and saves settings in its own directory) IRC client for Windows XP***, with rudimental scripting (***authenticating, automatically joining channels, reconnecting upon disconnect***) and log support (***so it can be left in the  background, so I can read the transcript later***).

Anyone know of such?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [portable install option for XChat-WDK](http://code.google.com/p/xchat-wdk/). I think that should fit your requirements perfectly, as it has logging, scripting, and plenty of options. It's very user friendly for the most port. It appears to store everything in a single directory, as requested.

Comment: In your network settings, there is an option to add in Nickserv authentication, or auto commands. It should also automatically reconnect. It does for me by default at any rate

Comment: you'd be better off getting it from the xchat-wdk site itself http://code.google.com/p/xchat-wdk/ The installer has a portable option. I've gotten it to authenticate and reconnect the same way i would on a regular system

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Fixed my link with that one, thanks for it

Comment: Yup, xchat definitely changed in the meantime (for the better :)))

Comment: @SimonSheehan - or http://www.xchat-wdk.org/

Comment: one of the confusing things about xchat on windows is there are three different versions - the shareware official version, silverex (which has good theme support with a theme switcher, but is outdated) and WDK, which has the best support for plugin languages, portable support, but a PITA way of switching themes and some missing plugins.I use WDK with a modified silverex theme, and plugins off silverex